# What is the meaning of cascading authorizations while revoking in SQL?

Tags: database, security, authorization

Suppose a person Y grants access to person A (with grant option) to resource A at t = 20. Person Z grants access (with grant option) to person A again to the same resource at t = 50, Person A grants access to person B at t = 30 and to person C at t = 60.

If later Y revokes As access to resource R, comment about the status of Bs and Cs access to the resource?

Comment: "..later Y revokes As access to resource R," - I think you mean resource A? In any case I would expect that B and C would not have their access changed. However, I'm not sure what your base question is.

Comment: sorry for typo. that is resource A, thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

B revoked  and C granted. 
The reason is that A granted access to B at t=30 before Z granted to A at t=50. When Y revoke the grant still A has access to that resource. All the grants from A will remain after t=50. Here, B is granted at t=30 so it revoked and C is granted at t=60, and that is after Z granted to A, so it remains as it is.